# Implementing System.Window.Forms in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms

I have been trying to find a way to add a notify Icon to an app I am writing in WPF C#.  I have found many links to [WPF NotifyIcon](https://bitbucket.org/hardcodet/notifyicon-wpf/) and while it does do what I want,5 its adds tens of megs to the memory footprint of a 5-8 meg footprint app.  It is a bit overkill.

I have also found many tutorials on how to use System.Window.Form to do this and most of them just say to reference them (I assume this means using the 'using' directive).  When I try it gives me and error saying that that "forms" doesn't exist in the namespace "Windows".  I thought maybe this was outdated and depreciated but I came across the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) for NotifyIcon and it looks current to 4.5.

Is there another way I should be implementing this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What solution did you choose for implenting the icon finally?

Comment: @sprinter252 I ended up using David Anson's "MinimizeToTray" from his blog at http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9889700 with the help of SimCard.  Worked like a charm and added almost nothing to the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio:

In the Solution Explorer expand your project and right click on "References"

Go to "Add Reference..."

[image]

In the Reference Manager, go to Assemblies -> Framework.

Scroll to System.Windows.Forms and check the box to include the assembly in your project.

[image]

You should now be able to add packages under the Windows.Forms assembly.

Comment: Wow with screen shots and all.  Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for.  Works like a charm and is slim as heck.

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark this as the answer if you thought it answered your question.